# Reverse sorting a Map by value in Java using stream

Tags: java, dictionary, java-stream

I have a TreeMap that looks like that:

```java
{AMZ=12.733334, APL=10.133334, FBK=21.4, GGL=30.599998, GHB=4.6, MCS=11.433334}
```

**I want to only retains the entries containing the 3 highest values.** I tried to do it that way:

```java
TreeMap<String, Float> ThreeBestStocksMean = new TreeMap<>();
ThreeBestStocksMean = stocksMean.entrySet()
       .stream()
       .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
       .limit(3)
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (key1, key2) -> key1, TreeMap::new));
System.out.println(ThreeBestStocksMean.toString());
```

I get this:

```java
{APL=10.133334, GHB=4.6, MCS=11.433334}
```

As you can see it is the exact opposite of what I want. It gave me the 3 lowest value although I want the 3 highest.

Do I use `Comparator.reverseOrder()` wrongly? In fact it produces the exact same result as if it wasn't there. I also tried with `Map.Entry.<String, Float>comparingByValue().reversed()` for the same result.

**Edit:**

The code above works, I had some leftovers in my code above that made it not work.

Comment: Have you recompiled your code? Works on my machine™ : `{AMZ=12.733334, FBK=21.4, GGL=30.599998}`

Comment: Indeed it works, I had some leftovers in my code above that made it not work. Sorry I'm stupid…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try building/compiling the code, I tried replicating the code as below and I am getting the expected output - {AMZ=12.733334, FBK=21.4, GGL=30.599998}

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class MyClass {
public static void main(String args[]) {
  TreeMap<String, Double> ThreeBestStocksMean = new TreeMap<>();
  TreeMap<String, Double> stocksMean = new TreeMap<>();
  stocksMean.put("AMZ",12.733334);
  stocksMean.put("APL",10.133334);
  stocksMean.put("FBK",21.4);
  stocksMean.put("GGL",30.599998);
  stocksMean.put("GHB",4.6);
  stocksMean.put("MCS",11.433334);

  ThreeBestStocksMean = stocksMean.entrySet()
   .stream()
   .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
   .limit(3)
   .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (key1, key2) -> key1, TreeMap::new));
   System.out.println(ThreeBestStocksMean.toString());
 }
}
```

Comment: Indeed it worked from the beginning.